# Sort on 2 fields and desending on second field from a list

Tags: python-3.x

Hi I am trying to sort on two fields on a list read from a data file. Now whilst the sort works correctly what I am trying to achieve is: I have three fields- Classcode, Name, Score. Now the program sorts on the name field first and then the score field in ascending order. However, I cannot get it to sort on the score field in descending order.

The code I have is:

```
import random
q=0
ans=0
studentnames = []
ascending = []


classcode = input("Enter your class (1,2 or 3): ")

if classcode == '1':
name=input("Enter your name: ")
n= int(input("Enter the number of questions you want to attempt: "))

#writing details to a txt file group1

text_file1 = open("data.dat", "a")


while q<n:                  
    c = random.randint(1,3)
    print("c is: ", c)

    if c==1:   
        f="+"

        num1 = random.randint(0,12)
        print("num1 is: ", num1)

        num2 = random.randint(0,10)
        print("num2 is: ", num2)

        product=num1*num2
        difference=num1-num2
        total=num1+num2

        d=total

        q+=1

        print("\n Question ", q)
        print ("What is  ",num1,f,num2," ? ")

        l=int(input("Enter Your Answer: "))
        if l==d:
            print ("\nCongratulations! your answer is right.\n")
            ans+=1
        else:
            print("\n I'm afraid your answer is wrong. The correct one is" ,d)            

    elif c==2:         
        f="*"

        num1 = random.randint(0,12)
        print("num1 is: ", num1)

        num2 = random.randint(0,10)
        print("num2 is: ", num2)

        product=num1*num2
        difference=num1-num2
        total=num1+num2

        d=product


        q+=1

        print("\n Question ", q)
        print ("What is  ",num1,f,num2," ? ")

        l=int(input("Enter Your Answer: "))
        if l==d:
            print ("\nCongratulations! your answer is right.\n")
            ans+=1
        else:
            print("\n I'm afraid your answer is wrong. The correct one is" ,d)

    else:         
        f="-"

        num1 = random.randint(0,12)
        print("num1 is: ", num1)

        num2 = random.randint(0,10)
        print("num2 is: ", num2)

        product=num1*num2
        difference=num1-num2
        total=num1+num2

        d=difference

        q+=1 # counter for questions

        print("\n Question ", q)
        print ("What is  ",num1,f,num2," ? ")

        l=int(input("Enter Your Answer: "))
        if l==d:
            print ("\nCongratulations! your answer is right.\n")
            ans+=1 # counter for answers
        else:
            print("\n I'm afraid your answer is wrong. The correct one is" ,d)

# calculating the percentage
x=float(ans)
y=float(q)
z=ans*100/q
cp=int(z)
print("Your Correct percentage = ",cp,"%\n")

#store details in a list
scores=[classcode,name,cp]
print(scores)

#writing to text file
text_file1.write(classcode )
text_file1.write(' ')
text_file1.write(name )
text_file1.write(' ')

#converting score to string so that it can be written to txt file
scr = str(cp)
text_file1.write(scr )

#adding a new line after each students score
text_file1.write("\n")

#close the txt file after it has been used
text_file1.close()

#reading the txt file
text_file1 = open("data.dat", "r")
print(text_file1.read())
text_file1.close()



import operator

with open("data.dat") as f:
students = []
for line in f:
fields = line.split()
students.append( (fields[0], fields[1], int(fields[2])) )

# sort by the student's name
sortedByName = sorted(students, key=operator.itemgetter(1,2))

for r in sortedByName:
classcode, name, score = r
print("name:", name, "classcode:", classcode, "score:", score)
```

The date that it outputs is:
name: 1 classcode: 1 score: 100

name: 2 classcode: 1 score: 100

name: aguero classcode: 1 score: 50

name: aguero classcode: 1 score: 100

name: aguero classcode: 1 score: 100

name: aguero classcode: 1 score: 100

name: alanshearer classcode: 1 score: 100

name: deniro classcode: 1 score: 100

name: deniro classcode: 1 score: 100

name: fabregas classcode: 1 score: 0

name: fabregas classcode: 1 score: 100

name: maradonna classcode: 1 score: 100

name: maradonna classcode: 1 score: 100

name: maradonna classcode: 1 score: 100

name: messi classcode: 1 score: 100

name: messi classcode: 1 score: 100

name: pacino classcode: 1 score: 50

name: pacino classcode: 1 score: 66

name: ronaldo classcode: 1 score: 33

name: ronaldo classcode: 1 score: 66

name: ronaldo classcode: 1 score: 66

name: ronaldo classcode: 1 score: 100

name: ronaldo classcode: 1 score: 100

name: ronaldo classcode: 1 score: 100

name: rooney classcode: 1 score: 50

name: rooney classcode: 1 score: 100

name: rooney classcode: 1 score: 100

name: rooney classcode: 1 score: 100

name: rooney classcode: 1 score: 100

name: rooney classcode: 1 score: 100

name: test1 classcode: 1 score: 100

name: test1 classcode: 1 score: 100

name: test2 classcode: 1 score: 100

name: test2 classcode: 1 score: 100

name: test3 classcode: 1 score: 20

name: test3 classcode: 1 score: 50

name: test3 classcode: 1 score: 60

name: test4 classcode: 1 score: 50

name: test4 classcode: 1 score: 60

name: test5 classcode: 1 score: 33

name: vanpersie classcode: 1 score: 100

name: vanpersie classcode: 1 score: 100

name: vanpersie classcode: 1 score: 100

name: vanpersie classcode: 1 score: 100

name: vanpersie classcode: 1 score: 100

name: vidal classcode: 1 score: 50

name: vidal classcode: 1 score: 50

name: vidal classcode: 1 score: 50

name: vidal classcode: 1 score: 50

name: vidal classcode: 1 score: 66

name: vidal classcode: 1 score: 100

name: vidal classcode: 1 score: 100

name: vidal classcode: 1 score: 100

name: yaya classcode: 1 score: 0

name: yaya classcode: 1 score: 50

name: yaya classcode: 1 score: 100

name: yaya classcode: 1 score: 100

name: yaya classcode: 1 score: 100

What I would like to achieve is order by name in ascending(which is currently fine) and by score in descending which I cant do yet.

Thanks

Comment: Solved. I have achieved this sort by using- sortedByName = sorted(students, key= lambda x: (x[1],-x[2]))

Comment: The only problem is it doesn't seem to like sorting names with capital letters